# Rename "ios8" tag to "ios-8" and create synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Tags exist for each version of iOS have hyphens in their name, such as [ios-7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-7), with synonyms for the tag without the hyphen.

However, with iOS 8, the [ios-8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-8) does not exist and instead the only tag is [ios8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios8).

Can this be rectified to be in the same style as the other versions of iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. I've made the rename and synonym. Thanks