# Rename [ios10] to [ios-10] for consistency

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

It's happened again! Just like [last time with iOS 8](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2145/rename-ios8-tag-to-ios-8-and-create-synonym), can [ios10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios10) be renamed to [ios-10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-10) for consistency with the tags for the other versions of iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes please and thank you.

I have modified the tags as suggested.